# Scan Barcode using external Barcode Scanner and act as onTapGesture SWIFTUI

Tags: swiftui

Just want to ask if anyone could help me.

[image: POS]

What I see: I have SearchBar Struc that are able to search items either SKU or LABEL (Product Name)

What to expect: I have list of items which has sku that I want to be able to
scan and act as onTapGesture that which call Add to Cart Method

This are my current codes:

```
struct ShowItemList: View {
@StateObject       var itemVM = ProductViewListModel()
@EnvironmentObject var order:  OrderViewModel
@State var searchtext = ""

var body: some View {
    SearchItem(searchtext: $searchtext) // Search textfield
    ItemListHeader() // Header sa Item List
    ScrollView {
        ForEach(itemVM.item.filter({searchtext.isEmpty ? true : $0.sku.contains(searchtext) || $0.label.contains(searchtext)})) { dataPoint in
            ZStack{
            HStack{
                Text(dataPoint.label)
                    .frame(width:220, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
                    .padding(.leading,30)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(dataPoint.price)")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
                Spacer()
                Text("\(dataPoint.quantity)")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
            }
            .padding(.leading, -20)
            .padding(.trailing, 20)
            .padding(.top, 5)
            .padding(.bottom, 5)
        }.onTapGesture {
            self.order.AddToCart(item: dataPoint.product) // Add to Cart Method
        }.alert(isPresented: $order.isValid) {
            Alert(title: Text("Not enough stocks remaining"), message: Text("Adjust item or PO item"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
            Divider()
        }
      }
    .onAppear(perform: itemVM.fetchProduct)
    .padding()
   }
 }

// SEARCH TEXTFIELD

struct SearchItem: View {
@Binding var searchtext: String

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            .padding(.leading, 13)
        TextField("Search", text: $searchtext)
            .padding(.leading, -10)
        .padding()
            .background(Color.white)
    }
    .frame(height: 50, alignment:.center)
    .border(Color.gray)
    .cornerRadius(3.0)
    .padding()
   }
 }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if not clear above. What I want is when I use external barcode scanner I want to call method Add to Cart if Item barcode exist.

Comment: Nobody can asnwer your question.  Talk to the manufacturer of your scanner as to how to access the machine.

Comment: @ElTomato noted thanks

Comment: If your external scanner device send a return in the end of the scan (I assume it does), you can use `.onSubmit` to call a function when the focus (cursor) is on the textfield to find the item if it exists and then add it to the cart, but I am not sure if you really want that. This would also happen if you enter a number manually and then press the `return` key.